# PHP and XmlWriter change indent string

Tags: php, xml, laravel, xmlwriter

I'm using laravel 5 and I try to output xml file using XMLWRITER.
Is it possible to change indent string from "one space" to "tabulation" ?

My actual code :

```
    $xml = new \XMLWriter();
    $xml->openMemory();
    $xml->setIndent(4);
    $xml->startDocument('1.0','UTF-8','yes');
    $xml->startElement('immeuble');
    $xml->writeAttribute('nature-immeuble', 'test');
    $xml->startElement('adresse');
    $xml->writeAttribute('localite', 'Copropriete');
    $xml->writeAttribute('libelle-pays', 'France');
    $xml->startElement('cadastre');
        $xml->writeAttribute('section', 'AA');
        $xml->writeAttribute('numero', '0000');
        $xml->endElement();
        $xml->endElement();
    foreach($lots as $lot) {
        $xml->startElement('lot');
        $xml->writeAttribute('numero', $lot->id);
        $xml->writeAttribute('type', 'appartement');
        $designation = getDesignation2($lot->id);
        $xml->writeAttribute('designation', $designation);
        $xml->writeAttribute('batiment', substr($lot->etageLots->first()->etage->batiment->nom, 0, 5));
        $xml->writeAttribute('etage', $lot->etageLots->first()->etage->coeff_id);
        if(is_null($lot->tantieme_force)){
            $tantieme = round($lot->tantieme_calcul,0);
        }else{
            $tantieme = $lot->tantieme_force;
        }
        $xml->writeAttribute('milliemes-generaux', $tantieme.$base);
        $xml->endElement();
    }
    $xml->endElement();
    $xml->endDocument();

    $content = $xml->outputMemory();
    $xml = null;

    return response($content)->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```

It gived me right xml but every lines are indent with one space before and actually I want a tabulation.

Is it possible to change this setting ?

I saw set indent string but I didn't find a way to use it with tabulation.

Thank for your help.

Comment: Seams like `$xml->setIndent();` waiting for a boolean, not the number of expected space, i can't try but maybe https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-set-indent-string.php is what you looking for

Comment: Is it possible to set a tabulation inside set indent string ? I don't find a html code for tabulation.

Comment: I don't think it exists but you can try `$xml->setIndentString("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;")`

Comment: sadly it doesn't work : error on line 3 at column 7: Entity 'nbsp' not defined

Comment: with the `$xml->setIndent(true);` before ?

Comment: hmmm try with single quote then

Comment: no more error but only one space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to indent with tabulation then use it like this:

```php
$xml->setIndent(true);
$xml->setIndentString("\t");
```